# Bulk geocoding for associating addresses to shapefiles [here-api]

Tags: geocoding, here-api

I was wondering if I can use the here-api to geocode addresses (bulk way) and store the results. I need to store them on a python data frame to afterwards merge them with a shape file. However, in the TOS HERE says that you cannot store the results from geocoding.

Answer (score 0):

I've been in your situation. Let me list the options that we've considered.

1. You could fetch address information dynamically using their Geocoding API. Advantage is that you'll always have up-to-date information, and you don't need to query places that you'll never use anyway.
2. I'm assuming that your shape file is based on HERE data. You could still try to use OpenStreetMaps. You'll get some inaccuracies if the map data differs, but it's free, and not as restrictive as HERE.
3. You could opt to buy the HERE map data, to work around the TOS restrictions

By the way, we went for an option 4: switching to OpenStreetMaps entirely, but it sounds like you don't have that luxery, because you have to work with existing shapefiles that you want to "enrich".